# Is data streaming via TCP socket connection safe when client and server are load balanced?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, nio, file-transfer

I am implementing a data streaming transfer mechanism that goes like this:

Client A wants to send a file to server B on a certain port. A and B will exchange a series of messages (writing to and reading from the connection stream) via a socket channel. A can have multiple concurrent requests to B.

```
A opens a connection with B.
A -> B: "I want to send a file"
B -> A: "OK, go ahead"
A -> B: "Here's 500KB of data..."
B -> A: "OK, I'm done reading that, send the next chunk"
A -> B: "Here's 500KB of data..."
B -> A: "OK, I'm done reading that, send the next chunk"
...and so on... until:
A -> B: "I'm done"
B -> A: "Ok bye."
A closes connection with B.
```

If A and B are load balanced, would this be safe? That is, if instance A1 connects with instance B1, then the **entire** transaction above will be between those two instances? That is, at no point will the messages written by A1 go to instance B2 instead?

For what it's worth, I am using `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel` in blocking mode to implement this.

Comment: If the whole transaction is happening inside a single TCP connection, then you are guaranteed that the endpoints of the transaction won't change, simply because TCP doesn't support that.  i.e. once a TCP connection is set up, it is permanently associated with the two original endpoints and the only way to communicate with any other host is to set up a new/additional TCP connection.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner and by "a single TCP connection", we would be talking about a new "conversation" that starts when an "accept()" listener answers the initial request, and all subsequent messages until the client closes that "conversation", correct? And a single port can serve multiple concurrent "conversations" like this?

If not, what would be the proper term to describe the space in which this "conversation", or transaction, takes place? Would a "channel" make sense?

Comment: @Zoomzoom: A "TCP connection" is what you get after `accept()` returns successfully. It consists of two endpoints each of which has an IP address and a port. As each new client connects, the server endpoint retains the same port as it was listening on, but the client IP address and/or port will be different every time. This allows the kernel is distinguish these TCP "connections" from each other and send network traffic to the correct process and queue on the server.

Comment: @JamesKPolk So I'm trying to ensure Jeremy's answer/comment applies to my case. Given what you both said, I believe it does. That is, for each of these connections between one of the A instances and one of the B instances, the end points are persistent throughout. So if instance A1 starts a connection with B1, A1 and B1 will be the pair of endpoints from beginning to end. Would you agree?

Comment: @Zoomzoom: Absolutely.

Comment: One of you guys please feel free to convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it, thanks!